# Определение цвета каждого пикскеля с помощью Jimp

Tags: javascript, node.js, изображения

Мне нужно по очереди узнать цвет каждого пикселя и производить в программе вычисления . Я хочу использовать jimp , но не знаю как . Прошу помощи у вас .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7EMB.png), cкрипт:

```
const jimp = require('jimp');

(async () => {

  const img = await jimp.read(`${__dirname}/q.png`);

  for (
    const { x, y, idx }
    of
    img.scanIterator(0, 0, img.bitmap.width, img.bitmap.height)
  ) {

    const colorHex = img.getPixelColor(x, y);

    const colorRgba = jimp.intToRGBA(colorHex);

    console.log(`x=${x}, y=${y}:    colorHex=${colorHex}, colorRgba=${JSON.stringify(colorRgba)}`);
  }

})();
```

Вывод:

```
x=0, y=0:    colorHex=0, colorRgba={"r":0,"g":0,"b":0,"a":0}
x=1, y=0:    colorHex=4294967295, colorRgba={"r":255,"g":255,"b":255,"a":255}
x=2, y=0:    colorHex=4211607807, colorRgba={"r":251,"g":8,"b":8,"a":255}
x=0, y=1:    colorHex=16904447, colorRgba={"r":1,"g":1,"b":240,"a":255}
x=1, y=1:    colorHex=50276095, colorRgba={"r":2,"g":255,"b":38,"a":255}
x=2, y=1:    colorHex=4277994239, colorRgba={"r":254,"g":253,"b":2,"a":255}
```

В документации это - раздел [Low-level manipulation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#low-level-manipulation).

Comment: Спасибо , выручили . Удачи вам и всего хорошего